# Why isn't mix-blend-mode working on the font/text in this CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use the CSS `mix-blend-mode` to make this text dodge over the background image but the css only seems to work on the div's background. I've seen it work on text before so why isn't it working here?

```
#draggable { mix-blend-mode: color-dodge; }
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YyJGzo

Comment: i think `mix-blend-mode` won't work for draggable elements,try without draggability.

Comment: @Raviteja no, it works on the div's background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The settings that you are using (text color and blend mode) are not noticeable

From the [w3c page](https://drafts.fxtf.org/compositing/#blendingcolorburn)

> 10.1.8. color-burn blend mode
>
> Darkens the backdrop color to reflect the source color. Painting with
>   white produces no change.
>
> if(Cb == 1)
>
> ```
> B(Cb, Cs) = 1
> ```
>
> else if(Cs == 0)
>
> ```
> B(Cb, Cs) = 0
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
> B(Cb, Cs) = 1 - min(1, (1 - Cb) / Cs)
> ```

Where Cb == 1 means white in the backdrop (the text in your case), and B(Cb, Cs) = 1 means that the resulting color stays white. (Without any contribution from the background)

Try

```
#draggable{ 
    color: green;
    mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
```

or

```
#draggable{ 
    color: grey;
}
```

demo [codepen with grey text](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwypXB)
for instance

Comment: screen is just a different setting. what do you mean it's not noticeable?

Comment: I mean that white on top of any color, and blended with color burn, will always give white, that is wht you are getting. I have added an example that hopefully is what you want.

Comment: Can you please add the bit about white into your answer? Thanks!